# Exchange/Outlook Rules

Tags: email, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

Scenario:
Exchange 2013 (yes, I know... currently planning to move to M365)

so, we have our accounting inbox
accounting@company.com
that inbox has two additional email addresses assigned
invoice.accounting@... and confirmation.accounting@...

Now what I want to have is that all emails to invoicing@ go to a folder invoicing, and all emails to confirmation go to a folder confirmation.
However if I log into OWA for accounting and try to create a rule, I can only select the accounting@ account (with all three email adresses.
Any idea how to make my accounting team happy?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the rule *with specific words in the recipients address* is for. If that won't work, use the *with specific words in the message header* rule.

Comment: Hey,

Thank you for your answer!

If I log into the accounting inbox go to otions -> organize emails -> inbox rules
I can create these rules:
* Create a new rule for arriving messages
* Move messages from someone to a folder
* Move messages with specific words in the subject to a folder
* Move message sent to a group or a folder
* Delete messages...

Which is the specific words int eh recipients adress you wrote about?

Comment: You have to create the rule yourself. Choose "Create a new rule for arriving messages" -> "More options" -> Then set "with specific words in the recipients address" (I don't have an English Exchange 2013 atm, so my wording may be off)

Comment: Ok, I switched the OWA language to EN, to get one level of translation out :)

create new rule for arriving messages -> more options... -> it includes these words... (menu) in the recipients address (new window opens)
invoice@company.com -> + -> OK
Do the following -> Move to -> the folder where I want it.
SAVE
rule is checked

But: does not work :-(
Mail gets delivered to inbox

Comment: Try with "invoice" only

Comment: Hi Lenniey,
Thank you for your answer.
I changed the invoice@company.com to invoice.
Did not work.
Is it maybe case sensitive?
I emailed to Invoice from my own (external) email account, so a match in invoice, if case sensitive, would have not matched.

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm that you want someone sends emails to  invoice.accounting@ will be sent to 
subfold of invoicing under accounting@company.com's inboxis?  If you want so, you can combine inbox rule with transport rule.

Firstly, open EAC, create a new rule, request: when recipient is invoice.accounting@, do the following, prepend the suject of the message with [invoice] and redirect the message to accounting@company.com.

Secondly, open OWA, choose accounting@company.com, create inbox rule, requests: apply this rule after the message arrives with [invoice] in the subject and move it to the invoice folder.

Do the same for confirmation.accounting@

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

I will try that on monday (weekend starts at 12 :D )
is it possible, that this does not work, because half of my infrastructure is still on Exchange2007 (I know...)?
The Rule I created said something like this (... you need to create a similar rule on the 2007 exchange...)

Comment: Ok, I tried that (sorry, for the long response time).
It did not work.
however I think I now know, why it does not.
The Hub transport is still on the old 2007 Exchange, that I want to get rid of (sorry, I forgot to tell that).
That means, all your hints where basically correct, but do not work, because all email related work is done on the "other" machine.

Sorry for mixing it up!
I will bookmark this and come back, once we have fully migrated.

Best regards